# TypeORM DON'T RUN migrations that I generated

Tags: mysql, orm, typeorm, database-migration, node.js-typeorm

I'm using TypeORM to map schema database that I have created with a MySQL script. My entities have already been created in TypeORM syntax and I want to generate the SQL code of them. The problem appear when I try to run the migration of the script generated by TypeORM and don't work, the terminal only show me:

```
query: SELECT VERSION() AS `version`
query: SELECT \* FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'levels' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
query: SELECT \* FROM `levels`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
No migrations are pending
```

However, TypeORM did generate a .ts file with the creations of the tables in a folder "migrations" from my proyect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJMuf.png)

The configuration of my AppDataSource is this:

```
// File in '/src/config/mysql.ts'

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "mysql",
    host: <string>process.env.HOST_DB,
    port: 3306,
    username: <string>process.env.USER_DB,
    password: <string>process.env.PASSWORD_DB,
    database: <string>process.env.DB,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    entities: [User, Album, Genre, Playlist],
    migrations: [__dirname + "/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
    migrationsRun: true,
});

export { AppDataSource };
```

The scripts that I execute in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./src/config/mysql.ts",
    "m:gen": "npm run typeorm migration:generate",
    "m:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run"
},
```

The command I ran to generate a migration that WORKED FOR ME was: `npm run m:gen -- src/migrations/test1`

The command for me to run the migration is: `npm run m:run`

I only need that TypeORM executes the .ts file that it generated, but I can’t make it work.

Comment: in you `migrations/` directory, do you have some files other than `migration` file - like some helper file?

Comment: No, the folder always be empty until I generate the first migration.

Comment: for test you can try to set `migrations` to `[test116...]` (name of your generated migration class), instead of existing `migrations: [__dirname + "/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],`
That way you can verify that things are working in general (if it finds migration and executes it), and that something with your path is not correct. To fix your path, currently you need to go back one directory (from config) and then to find `migrations` directory, so something like `['../migrations/*{.ts,.js}]`